# Unable to add my credential to checkout perforce in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, perforce

I want to checkout files from my perforce server, have added plugin in Jenkins for perforce.
But while checking the "Test Connection" it is throwing below error message.

**Connection Error: P4: Invalid credentials. Giving up...**

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Manage Jenkins-->Configure System-->Perforce

In the *Perforce Credentials* field, select "Add" to bring up oodles of credential options. You can add your username/password or P4 ticket, etc.

Comment: have tried the same but after adding data there is one option named "Test Connection", just to check that click on that option and that time getting error message as mentioned above